# How can I join/concatenate multiple Videos with different video formats / encoding using mencoder or ffmpeg using command line in linux?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding, mencoder

How can I join/concatenate multiple Videos with different video formats / encoding using mencoder or ffmpeg using command line in linux?

I have multiple videos in different fps (eg. 29 and 19) and encoder (eg. raw and h264), but resolution is the same to all of these video eg. 1280x720.

How can I merge them into a single video file? 
Kdenlive with full quality make a huge file (from 2.7gb to 8gigas), and quality is very bad from the initial one.

Comment: Generally, one converts *all* files to intermediate format, e.g. TS, and then concatenate and change the TS files to the preferred output format all at once.

Comment: Can you provide a ffmpeg / mencoder example code line that keeps the quality?

Comment: Convert all inputs to a common set of attributes by using filters. See duplicate link for example command.